# IIS vs Apache Site setup comaprison

Tags: apache, iis

Do we have Application Pool concept of IIS in Apache. So that I can isolate misbehaving site from the working one while making the Apache configuration changes.

Comment: Is this related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960364/site-level-apache-configurations-in-linux)?

Comment: Yes, I just want to know if application pool concept is possible in the Apache.